# How to invoke __init__ under multiple inheritance?

Tags: python

How to invoke `Xls.__init__` under Customer

If I tried `super(Customer, self).__init__(arg)`

But got the exception `*** TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`

I guess it tried to invoked `object`'s init()

So How can I do ? Thanks

```
class Xls():
    """docstring for Xls"""
    def __init__(self, xls_fname):
        super(Xls, self).__init__()
        self.xls_data = {} # Store the whole Excel Data

    def read_workbook(self, xls_fname):
        print("{0} called workbook".format(self.__class__))
        self.xls_name = xls_fname
        self.rd_bk = xlrd.open_workbook(xls_fname)

class Customer(object, Xls, xls_oper.ReadWrite):
    """docstring for Customer"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.read_workbook(arg)
        ap(self.xls_name)
        ap(self.xls_data)
```

Comment: Small nitpick: `__init__` is the initializer, not the constructor. The new object is already constructed (and bound to `self`) and the initializer gets to set it up further. In Python, `__new__` would be the constructor, but you don't need that as often.

Answer (score 3):

You must make `Xls` inherit from `object` or leave out `object` altogether. By making `Customer` inherit from `object` you are mixing old-style and new-style class hierarchies and that is breaking. `super()` found `object.__init__` here, not `Xls.__init__`.

When you move `object` up to `Xls` it works:

```
class Xls(object):
    # ...
```

and

```
class Customer(Xls, xls_oper.ReadWrite):
    # ...
```

If you remove `object` altogether, you cannot use `super()`; name the base class directly:

```
class Xls():
    # ...
    def __init__(self, xls_fname):
        # no base classes, no need to call a super __init__
        self.xls_data = {} # Store the whole Excel Data

class Customer(Xls, xls_oper.ReadWrite):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, arg):
        # Call base class __init__ directly, pass in self explicitly
        Xls.__init__(self, arg)
```

Answer (score -3):

__ **init** __ is not a constructor - it's an initialization function.
Obviously, you want to invoke Xls init - and Super, selects the first parent class 
Use instead

```
Xls.__init__(self)
```

Comment: That is what `super()` is *for*, to look up the next `__init__` method in the MRO order. The problem is that the OP mucked up the inheritance of `object`. Note that `Xls.__init__()` takes an argument (apart from `self`).